# Переместить элемент словаря на новую позицию, сместив остальные элементы вниз по списку

Tags: python, json, словари

Есть файл `test.json` с содержимым:

```
{
    "овощи": [
        "картошка",
        "помидор",
        "морковь"
    ],
    "фрукты": [
        "абрикос",
        "апельсин",
        "яблоко"
    ],
    "орехи": [
        "кедровые",
        "грецкие",
        "кешью"
    ],
    "конфеты": [
        "шоколад",
        "карамель",
        "леденцы"
    ],
    "ягоды": [
        "черника",
        "слива",
        "черешня"
    ]
}
```

Нужно переместить элемент словаря на новую позицию, сместив остальные элементы вниз по списку.

Например, элемент `конфеты` имеет индекс `3`, его нужно переместить на индекс `1` где находится элемент `фрукты`.

```
     [0] овощи
+--> [1] фрукты
|    [2] орехи
+<-- [3] конфеты
     [4] ягоды
```

А остальные элементы сместить на позицию ниже:

```
     [0] овощи
     [1] конфеты <-- был на [3]
     [2] фрукты <-- был на [1]
     [3] орехи <-- был на [2]
     [4] ягоды
```

Я не нашел способа как это правильно сделать, но находил функцию **OrderedDict** с помощью которой мог бы перемещать элементы в начало или в конец списка, но он не делает то что я описал выше.

Как мне изменить местоположение элемента в списке?

Comment: Вставить и удалить не прокатит?

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей я не буду иметь прямого доступа к файлу. кроме меня этим файлом будут пользоваться еще несколько человек и удаленно им управлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# file_path = join ... "test.json"
# new_path = join ...

# Прочитать файл
with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Взять ключи
keys = collections.deque(data.keys())

# Извлечь ключ и вставить в новую позицию
keys.remove("конфеты")
keys.insert(1, "конфеты")

# Создать новый словарь с требуемой сортировкой
new_data = {key: data[key] for key in keys}

with open(new_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(new_data, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {
    "овощи": [
        "картошка",
        "помидор",
        "морковь"
    ],
    "фрукты": [
        "абрикос",
        "апельсин",
        "яблоко"
    ],
    "орехи": [
        "кедровые",
        "грецкие",
        "кешью"
    ],
    "конфеты": [
        "шоколад",
        "карамель",
        "леденцы"
    ],
    "ягоды": [
        "черника",
        "слива",
        "черешня"
    ]
}


def chg(dct, what, where):
    l = [k for k in dct]
    l.insert(l.index(where),l.pop(l.index(what)))
    return {k:dct[k] for k in l}

print(chg(d, "конфеты", "фрукты"))
```